# Sip demo not working in samsung galaxy Y 2.3.6

Tags: android

i have use the sip demo that work perfectly in emulator but when i run on mobile(Samsung galaxy Y 2.3.6) then the user registration not occure.There is internet connection is on but registration not occure.So can anybody know how to run on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check with SipManager.isApiSupported() and SipManager.isVoipSupported() is SIP is supported on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the phones (even if it is 2.3+) do not support SIP. You need to have your own SIP Stack to do it to work on all phones. Try customizing SipDroid Open Source project. It has its own Sip Stack.